# Generating pre-signed urls for S3 from Fargate Container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, aws-fargate, vpc

I'm trying to generate some presigned urls using boto3 but have failed so far. The code below works fine locally, but when I try to GET the generated urls from within a fargate container I receive 400. What I am currently doing:

```
# Getting creds for container
aws_container_credentials_uri = os.getenv("AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI")
            credentials = requests.get(f"http://169.254.170.2/{aws_container_credentials_uri}").content
            cred_str = credentials.decode("UTF-8")
            cred_dict = ast.literal_eval(cred_str)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=cred_dict["AccessKeyId"],
                                         aws_secret_access_key=cred_dict["SecretAccessKey"],
                                         aws_session_token=cred_dict["Token"],
                                         region_name="eu-central-1"
                                         )
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
                    ClientMethod='get_object',
                    Params={'Bucket': config.bucket_name, 'Key': f'test/audio.mp3'},
                    ExpiresIn=3600)
requests.get(url)
```

I am a little bit clueless as to why this is happening, I would appreciate any help!

Ps: I already checked the IAM permission for the Task role of the container and I am otherwise able to retrieve and upload objects from the correct bucket.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't checked the actual ECS task logs yet? Nobody can help you diagnose this until you go look at the logs to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I did check it, when I try to GET my files I receive a NOT AUTHORIZED 400

Comment: It sounds like your ECS task doesn't actually have the correct permissions to generate a presigned URL, so when you use the URL it generated it doesn't work. Are you sure you are assigning the correct permissions to the ECS task role (not the service role)?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, the permissions are correct. However, everything seems to point in either a IAM problem or a Network permission issue. I struggling to find reference as to which permission would be needed to generate the correct pre-signed url.